# How to resize window to fit content in WPF design view

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013

I'm creating a simple 'Noughts and Crosses' game in WPF design view using a 600 x 600 grid control. I'd like my window to fit perfectly around it in the design view. Is there a shortcut or button to allow me to do this? (to snap the edge of one control to another, for instance).

I've searched and I can only find help regarding the opposite situation (fitting the grid to fill/stretch to the window not vice-versa). I want to have a 600 x 600 fixed grid so that each 'tile' of the game will be exactly 200 x 200. When I set the window size to 600 x 600 then a grid is always smaller.

If there's not an automated way of doing it then maybe there's a set of UI measurements regarding window frame, window bar, menu bars etc? The only way I can think of calculating manually is to set my window to 600 x 600 then look at the size of a grid that's stretched to fill the window, this would give me the difference between the two sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can't you just simply name your grid and bind your window height and width to the grid h/w?

```
<Window .....
        Height="{Binding ElementName=myGrid, Path=Height}"
        Width="{Binding ElementName=myGrid, Path=Width}">
    <Grid x:Name="myGrid" Width="600" Height="600">
        <!--...-->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I went down the manual route, by sizing the window 600x600 then calculated how many pixels short the contained grid was, then extended the window by those measurements. I'm going to try your method as well (I'm assuming it binds to the grid measurements then allows the additional size of the window decoration?). Thanks for the suggestion!